# Undefined variable if count 0

Tags: php, mysql

i have a little bit problem with my following code. I am trying to make a star raiting system and following code is showing raiting details. But i am getting

> undefined variable rate_db notice

from `if(count($rate_db))` What i missing here anyone can tell me please ?

full code is here:

```
    <?php
      $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT ryid,r_type FROM profileRaiting WHERE rp_uid='$profile_uid'"); 
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
           $rate_db[] = $data;
           $sum_rates[] = $data['r_type'];
        }
        if(count($rate_db)){
          $rate_times = count($rate_db);
          $sum_rates = array_sum($sum_rates);
          $rate_value = $sum_rates/$rate_times;
          $rate_bg = (($rate_value)/5)*100;
        } else {
           $rate_times = 0;
           $rate_value = 0;
           $rate_bg = 0;
        }
 ?>
```

Comment: `$rate_db = array();` and `$sum_rates = array();` initialize at top

Comment: Since you define that variable `$rate_db` in your loop, it won't be defined if the loop never occurs (like with an empty result). Define that variable: `$rate_db = array()` before your loop.

Comment: Side note: You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. (there's always a risk when concatenating strings like that)

Comment: I guess php have variable scope too? you declare `$rate_db` inside the `while`  and outside isnt define?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - If you define a variable in a loop, then it will exist outside as well (after the loop, that is). But if the loop never gets triggered, then it will be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to initialize your both arrays at top as:

```
$rate_db = array(); 
$sum_rates = array();
```

*And i don't know where you define this variable `$profile_uid`, if it's user input or session value, than your code is open for SQL Injection, you can use Prepared Statement to prevent SQL attack. And this post will help you to understand: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*

**Side Note & Suggestion:**

One more thing, you can also get the sum of `r_type` as:

```
$sum_rates += $data['r_type'];
```

In this case, you need to initialize `$sum_rates` as:

```
$sum_rates = 0;
```

And just remove this line from IF condition:

```
$sum_rates = array_sum($sum_rates);
```

**Benefit**, no need to use extra method.

Comment: thank you for your nice answer. It is solved my problem. And i fixed SQL injection.

Comment: @DevStud: glad to help u friend.

Answer (score 2):

`$rate_db` variable is defined in the `while` loop where you fetch the data from MySQL. However, if the query does not return any records, then `while` loop's body will not be executed, thus `$rate_db` variable will not be defined.

Solution: define `$rate_db` variable as an empty array before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the variable:

```
<?php
        $rate_db = array();
        $sum_rates = array();
        $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT ryid,r_type FROM profileRaiting WHERE rp_uid='$profile_uid'"); 
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
           $rate_db[] = $data;
           $sum_rates[] = $data['r_type'];
        }
        $rate_times = count($rate_db);
        if($rate_times > 0){
          $sum_rates = array_sum($sum_rates);
          $rate_value = $sum_rates/$rate_times;
          $rate_bg = (($rate_value)/5)*100;
        } else {
           $rate_times = 0;
           $rate_value = 0;
           $rate_bg = 0;
        }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

before using count you need to be sure that it does have something in it so your complete code can be like this

```
<?php
  $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT ryid,r_type FROM profileRaiting WHERE rp_uid='$profile_uid'"); 
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
       $rate_db[] = $data;
       $sum_rates[] = $data['r_type'];
    }
    if(isset($rate_db) && count($rate_db)){
      $rate_times = count($rate_db);
      $sum_rates = array_sum($sum_rates);
      $rate_value = $sum_rates/$rate_times;
      $rate_bg = (($rate_value)/5)*100;
    } else {
       $rate_times = 0;
       $rate_value = 0;
       $rate_bg = 0;
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT ryid,r_type FROM profileRaiting WHERE rp_uid='$profile_uid'"); 
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
           $rate_db[] = $data;
           $sum_rates[] = $data['r_type'];
        }
```

Because when your query returns empty result the while loop will never become true, so $rate_db[] will never be reached and therefore will never be created.

to fix this, you should declare $rate_db[] as empty first at the top of your script. to avoid the error.